# What I missed? I can't find

Tags: php, html, parsing, mysqli

I have a little bit large code, I don't know if it's okay to post here. But I need help. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\icebm\Projekt\account.php on line 220 that's the message what I get, and I checked a million times if I missed something, but I can't find anything. This code has 220 lines, something is wrong with body or html tags? Thanks a lot if you take a look :)

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>ICEBM 2017</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Photos/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body onload="displayCalendar()" >
    <div class="tarolo">

        <!-- Slideshow beillesztese -->
        <div class="slideshow">

        <div class="slide">
          <img src="Photos/elso.png" style="width:100%; height:62%">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
          <img src="Photos/masodik.jpg" style="width:100%; height:62%">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
          <img src="Photos/harmadik.jpg" style="width:100%; height:62%">
        </div>

        </div> 

        <div style="text-align:center">
          <span class="dot"></span> 
          <span class="dot"></span> 
          <span class="dot"></span> 
        </div>
        <script src="Javascript/slideshow.js"></script>

        <!-- Menu beillesztese -->
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="helyszin.php">Location</a></li>
            <li><a href="bizottsag.php">Committee</a></li>
            <li><a href="szervezo.php">Organizing institutions</a></li>
            <li><a href="hataridok.php">Deadlines</a></li>
            <li><a href="palyazas.php">Application</a></li>
            <li><a href="kapcsolat.php">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="registration.php">Registration</a></li>
            <?php
                if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
                    echo '<li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>';
                else
                    echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>';
            ?>
        </ul>

        <div class="tartalom">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="Photos/logo.png" align="right" alt="logo"></a>
            <h1>Account Info</h1>

            <?php
            //session_start();
            if(isset($_POST['submission'])) {

                $filename = $_FILE["fileup"]["name"];
                $target_dir = "Uploads/"; //the directory where file will be uploaded
                $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileup"]["name"]);
                $uploadOk = 1;
                $filetype = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

                //check if the file is pdf
                if (!empty($_FILES['fileup']['name'])) {
                    if( mime_content_type($target_file) == "application/pdf" ) {
                        if ($_FILES["fileup"]["error"] > 0) {
                            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["fileup"]["error"] . "<br>";
                            $uploadOk = 0;
                        } 
                        else {
                            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["fileup"]["name"] . "<br>";
                            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["fileup"]["type"] . "<br>";
                            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["fileup"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br>";
                            echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["fileup"]["tmp_name"];
                            echo "<br>";
                            $uploadOk = 1;
                        }
                    }
                else {
                    echo "Invalid file!";
                }

                // Check if file already exists
                if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                    echo "Sorry, file already exists. <br>";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }

                 // Check file size
                /*if ($_FILES["fileup"]["size"] > 500000) {
                    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }*/

                // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
                if ($uploadOk == 0)
                    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded. <br>";
                // if everything is ok, try to upload file
                else {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileup"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
                        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileup"]["name"]). " has been uploaded. <br><br>";
                    else 
                        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. <br>";
                }

                //connect to mysql
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $database = "icebm";


                // Create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Csatlakozás sikertelen: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 
                //echo "Sikerült csatlakozni.";
                mysqli_query($conn,"set character set UTF8");

                $title = $_POST["paper"];
                $abstract = $_POST["abstract"];
                $author = $_POST["author"];
                $option = $_POST["option"];

                $insertinto = "INSERT INTO eloadas (cim, osszefoglalo, tarsszerzo, fajlnev, azonosito) VALUES  ('". $title ."', '". $abstract ."', '".$author."', '".$filename."', '".$option."') ";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $insertinto);
                /*if(!empty($result)) {
                    echo "sikerult";
                }*/
                $select = "SELECT eloadasID FROM eloadas";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
                /*if(!empty($result2)) {
                    echo "sikerultt";
                }*/
                while($eloadas = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $eloadasID = $eloadas['eloadasID'];
                    $felhasznalonev = $_SESSION['user'];

                $eredmeny = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO eloadast_tart VALUES ('".$eloadasID."', '".$felhasznalonev."')");
                /*if(!empty($eredmeny)) {
                    echo "sikerulttt";
                }*/
                }

            ?>
            <?php
                //connect to mysql
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $database = "icebm";

                // Create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) 
                    die("Csatlakozás sikertelen: " . $conn->connect_error);

                $nev=$_SESSION['user'];
                //SELECT cim FROM eloadas INNER JOIN eloadast_tart ON eloadas.eloadasID=eloadast_tart.eloadasID INNER JOIN jelentkezo ON eloadast_tart.felhasznalonev=jelentkezo.felhasznalonev WHERE felhasznalonev=$nev;
                $id = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT eloadasID FROM eloadast_tart WHERE felhasznalonev='".$nev."'");

                echo '<i>Title of submitted papers: </i><br>';
                while($row = $id->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $cim = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cim FROM eloadas WHERE eloadasID='".$row['eloadasID']."'");
                    while($x = mysqli_fetch_array($cim)) {
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo $x['cim'];
                    }
                }
                /*$parancs = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cim FROM eloadas INNER JOIN eloadast_tart ON eloadas.eloadasID=eloadast_tart.eloadasID INNER JOIN jelentkezo ON eloadast_tart.felhasznalonev=jelentkezo.felhasznalonev WHERE felhasznalonev='".$nev."'");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($parancs))
                    echo $row['cim'];*/
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="jobboldal">
            <div align="left">
                <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
                        echo '<a style="color:#7f1515;" href="submission.php" id="submission">Submission!</a>';
                ?>
            </div>

            <div align="right">

                <?php 
                    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                        echo '<img src="Photos/account.png" width="9%" height="4%">';
                        echo "<a href='account.php'>'".$_SESSION['user']."'</a>  ";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Visszaszamlalo -->
            <img src="Photos/days.png" width="100%">
            <p id="demo"></p> 
            <script src="Javascript/visszaszamlalo.js"></script>

            <!--Naptar beillesztese -->
            <div id="calendar"></div> 
            <script src="Javascript/naptar.js"></script>

            <p>Previous ICEBM pages: 
                <a href="https://econ.ubbcluj.ro/icebm/2015/">ICEBM 2015</a><br>
                <a href="https://econ.ubbcluj.ro/icebm/2013/">ICEBM 2013</a> </p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some of your if blocks are not closed by `}`.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submission'])) {` and `if (!empty($_FILES['fileup']['name'])) {` are not closed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not closing the following braces:

```
if(isset($_POST['submission'])) {
```

and

```
if (!empty($_FILES['fileup']['name'])) {
```

Comment: Oh my God, thank you sooo much! :D